# Teechart set num of decimals on Axis and hide Axis labels for further series

Tags: c++, c++builder, teechart

hope you can help me.
In Builder C++ create a new "Windows VCL Application". Add a "Tchart" from "Palette".
Right click on the chart -> Edit Chart -> Click on Series -> Add... -> Line -> Ok to create Series1 and repeat to create Series2.
Close
In Unit1.cpp copy my following sample:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
#include <vector>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)

{
    std::vector<float> x1, y1, x2, y2;

for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
     float r1 = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);
     float r2 = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);
     x1.push_back(i+r1);
     y1.push_back(r1);
     x2.push_back(i+r2);
     y2.push_back(r2);

}

Chart1->BottomAxis->AxisValuesFormat = "0.0";


for (unsigned i = 0; i < x1.size(); i++) {
    Chart1->Series[0]->AddY(y1[i], x1[i]);
    Chart1->Series[1]->AddY(y2[i], x2[i]);
}
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Compile and run. As you can see the values on the X axis appear overlapped.

[image: chart]

In order to solve I would

1. display the X axis values with only 1 decimal
2. hide the X axis labels for Series[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8k1s2.png) (i. e., Series2)

For the 1st point I've tried as you see in the code but it seems not working.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Nobody knows how to do that? Please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding points to the Line series with the `AddY` method, passing the x values as the second parameter, which is the label.
Doing so, the bottom axis labels indeed overlap.

Instead, I'd use the `AddXY` method, passing the x values as the first parameter and the y values as the second:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < x1.size(); i++) {
    Chart1->Series[0]->AddXY(x1[i], y1[i]);
    Chart1->Series[1]->AddXY(x2[i], y2[i]);
}
```

This looks fine for me here:

[image: chart]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the answer.